# What is the proper way to execute a requirements.txt file in a chef cookbook recipe to install python modules?

Tags: python, resources, chef-infra, dsl, execute

I am trying to learn chef and very new at it.

I have a `requirements.txt` file which I'm trying to execute through a chef recipe to install some Python modules. I have tried different variations of the code, however I feel like I'm missing something.  I have tried writing the following code in the chef recipe:

```
template '/etc' do
  source 'requirements.txt.erb'
  owner 'root'
  group 'root'
  mode '0644'
end

execute 'requirements.txt' do
  command 'pip install -r requirements.txt'
  action  'run'
end
```

I was expecting that the requirements file will be called when I run vagrant up and the modules/dependencies of the app will be installed. However, I get this error:

> Error executing action `run` on resource 'execute[requirements.txt]'

Answer (score 0):

Check this example from https://docs.chef.io/resource_execute.html

```
execute 'upgrade script' do
   command 'php upgrade-application.php && touch /var/application/.upgraded'
   creates '/var/application/.upgraded'
   action :run
end
```

You need to specify the run action as shown above (:run) rather than with single quotes as shown in your posted example.

Answer (score 0):

if i am not mistaken, i think that [coderanger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/78722/coderanger) developed a cookbook named [`python-poise`](https://github.com/poise/poise-python), which has [`pip_requirements`](https://github.com/poise/poise-python#pip_requirements) chef resource. it looks like:

```rb
pip_requirements '/opt/myapp/requirements.txt'
```